# getting syntax error while trying to use trigger in order to insert a row to another table

Tags: sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

As a school project ı am trying to add a trigger to my database. But I keep getting errors. What I am trying to do is when something is inserted to buy table ı want to update shopping_history table.

this is the code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER deneme AFTER INSERT ON buy
AS

BEGIN
INSERT INTO shopping_history(account_id,ticket_id,purchase_date,ticket_seat_no,company_name,ticket_price,ticket_from,ticket_to,ticket_date)
SELECT account.account_id,ticket.ticket_id,buy.purchase_date,ticket.seat_no,company.company_name,ticket.ticket_price,ticket.startpoint,ticket.destination,ticket.flight_time
FROM account,ticket,company, inserted 
WHERE account.account_id = inserted.account_id and inserted.ticket_id = ticket.ticket_id and company.company_id = ticket.company_id
END
$$
DELIMETER ;
```

This is the error ı keep getting

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON buy
AFTER INSERT

BEGIN
INSERT INTO shopping_history(account_id,ticket_id' at line 1
```

After some search ı discovered that ı required to use delimeters in order to make sure SQL sees this as one input. But that didn't really help me at my situation. I also learned ı need to use `BEGIN` and `END`
in the body of triggers but that wasn't also a solution

These are the tables ı use:

ticket =
|ticket_id|company_id|seat_no|frequency|flight_time|startpoint|destination|flight_id|ticket_price|

company =
|company_id|company_name|

account =
|account_id|password|mail|

buy =
|purchase date|ticket_id|account_id|

ı checked names and they are correct too. I don't know what is wrong.  Thanks for the help

Comment: The correct syntax is: `CREATE TRIGGER deneme AFTER INSERT ON buy`

Comment: @forpas well I also tried it but still getting the same error

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  In addition, learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

After some research ı found out that the problem was my website not updating the resource files. But pressing ctrl + f5 was useful.